# When two rows share the same input variable and target variable, is that leakage?

Tags: cross-validation

I am fitting various regression models using three categorical variables a date column, and some numeric columns. A lot of the rows have the same date. And it turns out, a lot of the rows that share a date, also have the same y-value.

Is it necessary to split the training and testing set in a way so that none of the dates in the training set are the same as the dates in the testing set?

Below is a very simplified version of the data I have, just as a means to illustrate the way the dates and the target variable relate.[image]

Comment: @lerner what network?

Comment: Why would they be ignored? I don't show it here but they are being encoded.

Comment: from the original question, I thought the yield depends only on the date. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, this is data leakage*. Whenever your model has information about your testing set that it would not have during real-time inference, that is data leakage.

For example, if you asked me to predict `yield` and told me the day was 735250 or 735265, I would have a pretty good accuracy. But if I needed to perform real-time inference, e.g. predict `yield` when the day was 735999, I would be a lot less accurate.

A large caveat, *just because you have data leakage does not mean you will overfit*. It depends entirely on whether or not your model would be able to exploit the information. A high capacity model like a neural network or a random forest would likely be able to, whereas a logistic regression may not be.

But why trust strangers on the internet? If you have enough data, take the most recent 20% of data as one test set, then shuffle the remaining data and take another 20% as a second test set. Train a model and compare performance between these two test sets. If there's no significant difference, then you shouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You now ask:

> Is it necessary to split the training and testing set in a way so that
>   none of the dates in the training set are the same as the dates in the
>   testing set?

No. Why would that be necessary? In fact, I think it would be a sign of trouble if that were the case.

Comment: I figured that if the testing set doesn't have any of the dates the model had when it was fit, that would reveal how much an effect the matching date/yield columns has. Can you elaborate on why that is a sign of trouble?

Comment: It would mean your method of randomizing into train and test had failed. And, since the train and test data sets would then be different in important ways, the results might not mean much.